# width html element for images in cakephp

Tags: php, html, cakephp

Hello I am trying to set the HTML width value in cake php however it doesn't seem to work. Any idea why?

```
    <div style="clear:both;" class="uploaddata padt10">
<?php echo $this -> Html -> image(GALLERY_LIST_IMAGE_URL . $data['Galleryimage']['main_image'], array('width' => '650')); ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description, also please always mention your exact CakePHP version! That being said, it works just fine over here.

Comment: Sorry! Hmmm i see, strange not sure why it isn't working for me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't just use CSS?

```
.uploaddata.padt10 img 
{
    width:650px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's true! I just love making life difficult :) Thanks! Would be nice to know why the cakephp way doesnt work though.